# Linker cannot find library

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

```
#include <wininet.h>
int main()
{


    auto res = InternetAttemptConnect(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Error I'm getting (I use code::blocks):**
undefined reference to `InternetAttemptConnect@4'|

Any one knows what library (which file) do I need to specify in linker settings to make it work?

Comment: @Mat I do have the webpage in front of me. The point is that I cannot provide a path for .dll file. That's why I'm asking. And those downvotes are because what? I don't know something obvious? Wow. Sorry for asking then.

Comment: *How* are you trying to link to the library? The entry in the settings should be `wininet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The point is that I cannot provide a path for .dll file.

At run-time your program will use the DLL, but at build-time you must link to the LIB associated with the DLL.

The LIB will be is in your compiler/SDK directory (and the paths to directories which contain your LIB files is a linker option).

Answer (score 0):

Link `Wininet.lib` for that.

[Using libraries with Code::Blocks](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/)

*P.S. You can just use Google to find out those kind of stuff.
It's very easy to find.*